# How do I access the parent fragment's children views from a ViewPager?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the following XML layout and inside my ViewPager there is a fragment that I am in. From within that fragment how do I access the MaterialToolBar?

```
<DrawerLayout
    <CoordinatorLayout
        <ViewPager
        <MaterialToolBar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after an hour, you have to repeatedly keep finding the parent fragment until you hit the correct one....

In my case I had to do `parentFragment?.parentFragment?.parentFragment?.my_toolbar?`

Is that supposed to be a great grandparents or something ...